# select an html element based on multiple attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose I get 3 attributes:

```
var uid = $("#main_container").attr("uid");
var ticker = $("#main_container").attr("ticker");
var exchange = $("#main_container").attr("exchange");
```

I want to get the anchor tag that matches those 3 attributes. I'm not sure how to do that with regards to where to put the quotes. Would it be:

```
$('a[uid='+uid+'][ticker='+ticker+'][exchange='+exchange+']')
```

or

```
$('a[uid="'+uid+'"][ticker="'+ticker+'"][exchange="'+exchange+'"]')
```

Comment: `$('a[uid="'+uid+'"][ticker="'+ticker+'"][exchange="'+exchange+'"]')`??

Comment: yes, fixing that error now. Is that the way to do it then? If yes, just add it as an answer and I'll give credit after testing :-)

Comment: [jQuery Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

Comment: @mdesdev, yes, the the confusion was how that would change if there are variables rather than text. where do the extra quotes go.

Comment: @user1357015 Ooh...always wrap single in double quotes or without mixing quotes when selecting half & half e.g. `$('#someId'+variable)` I'm always using singles except of course when I need mixing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is just that you have missed the parenthesis(used `<>` instead of `()`)

```
$('a[uid="' + uid + '"][ticker="' + ticker + '"][exchange="' + exchange + '"]')
```